# What is a good way to define a group of constants and use them?

Tags: typescript, class, object, enums, constants

For example let's say I have three constants:

```
const dog = {
    legs: 4,
    fur: "soft"
}

const grass = {
    color: "green",
    length: "short"
}

const house = {
    yearBuilt: 2005,
    roof: "NEW"
}
```

How can I call them so I can do something like this, without having to call their names one by one?

```
for (<every const in random.ts>) {
    doThis();
}
```

I looked into creating an enum with these three constants, but it looks like enums aren't good if you want to be able to edit the values. I'm considering using a class, but I'm not sure if that's the right implementation if I am only going to have constants. Are there any other options?

Comment: Add them to an array. Loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use constants you can use "const assertions" and create a object to iterate it.

For example:

```
let obj = {
  dog: {
    legs: 4,
    fur: "soft"
  },
  grass: {
    color: "green",
    length: "short"
  },
  house: {
    yearBuilt: 2005,
    roof: "NEW"
  }
 } as const;
```

Then you can access to values or key: value pair.

```
for(const item of Object.values(obj)) {
  console.log(item)
}

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key, value)
}
```

const assertions give you:

- no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going
  from “hello” to string)
- object literals get readonly properties
- array literals become readonly tuples